# Import CSV file with date times correctly into SAS

Tags: csv, date, time, import, sas

I have a CSV file containing DATE TIME variable. I have trouble importing it into SAS correctly. Below is the format of date time variable.
[image]

I would like to know how I can import this CSV file correctly and later split Sampling Date variable into DATE and TIME coumns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a CSV file (a text file) why have you posted at photograph of a spreadsheet? Please paste in some of the lines from the text file instead of the photograph.

Comment: Please remember to show what code you've tried per [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should output the desired result:

Input (csv file):

[image]

```
data want;
    infile "path\to\your\file" missover dsd dlm='7F'x;
    input id $ datetime :anydtdtm15.;
    date = datepart(datetime);
    time = timepart(datetime);

    drop datetime;
    format date ddmmyyd8. time time8.;
run;
```

Output (`want`):

[image]